# How to define conversation rules in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I really like the new conversation view in Outlook 2010. But I'm struggling with an issue.

On my companies social network site, it will send out email messages with a subject formatted like so "[Some Group] Some Subject".  When someone replies, the reply subject will be formatted "[Some Group] Re: Some Subject"

Unfortunately, Outlook does not recognize them as being the same conversation.  This is because the Re: comes after the square brackets instead of being at the beginning of the subject.  Is there a way to put a regex or something into Outlook 2010 to tell it that those subjects are a part of the same conversation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the conversation view settings.  Your best bet is to have Outlook run a VBA macro when it recieves similar mail.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Is there an API for grouping conversations?